# Android: How do they implement a dynamically changing listitems with fancy designs in a listview?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-listview, listitem

I am looking to implement a fancy listview meaning those that have listitems that have alot of formatting and numerous text and graphics like those you see in a news related app.

however searching for a right tutorial that fits something that I need is quite fleeting.
I see this but not quite: [Android app - how do I update my ListItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430801/android-app-how-do-i-update-my-listitem)

Anybody that knows a resource that shows how to do a fancy listitem with fancy formatting and dynamic behaviors, please let me know on how to do such as things for a new developer.

What i really like to learn to do is everything you see those news apps have of those really well designed listitems that have changing information and changing display and changing size and loading new UI items inside base on user touch.... i am not looking for the old stuff from those simple articles.

Thx in advance.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Implementing-a-Horizontal-ListView-Guide

Answer (score 0):

One example with all the mentioned work code is not avilable as example Cuz it would be seperate complete project. Here are example of dynamic listview
`

- `<http://sampleprogramz.com/android/listview.php>`
- Dynamically increase row of listview <`http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/09/dynamic-list-view-demo-in-android.html`>
- add items to ListView dynamically which gives the user an option to edit the<`http://www.javaexperience.com/how-to-create-a-dynamically-growing-listview-in-android/`>
- Customized Android ListView with Image and Text<`http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507651/Customized-Android-ListView-with-Image-and-Text`>
- Android horizontal listview library with item scroll <`http://profi.co/android-horizontal-list-view-library-with-item-scroll/`>

hope it helps :)

Comment: they do, are there any resources on creating fancy listitems? thx.